# PHP function calling sql SUM not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

don't know why this function not working

```
     function sumAll($row ,$monthNr, $first){
      $data = "SELECT SUM($row) FROM closeDay WHERE MONTH(dates) = $monthNr AND YEAR(dates) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
      $result = mysql_query($data);
      $query_data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
      $first = $query_data[0];
      return $first;
    }


//calling the function
sumAll('total' , 01, $first);
```

help please thanks

Comment: What's not working with it? You need to provide more details.

Comment: Seems like you are not passing any `$connection`. Try adding this. `$result = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());` to know the exact cause of your situation.

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What do you expect it to do? What does it do? What data is in the database?

Comment: put $monthNr inside single qoutations

Comment: i am not getting any error but the result is zero 
and if i call it out side the function working normal and giving me the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have non sence parameters in your function, try this:

```
   function sumAll($row,$monthNr){
  $data = "SELECT SUM(".$row.") sums FROM closeDay WHERE MONTH(dates) = '".$monthNr."' AND YEAR(dates) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
  $result = mysql_query($data);
  $query_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $first = $query_data['sums'];
  return $first;
}
```

call it like that:

```
 sumAll('total' , 01);
```